Is it possible to directly read or download a public Office365 XLSX file?
Here's a public link to an XLSX Office365 file. You don't need any credentials to access it.
Is there anyway to programmatically download a file like this?
Obviously, this doesn't work.
readxl::read_excel("https://onedrive.live.com/view?id=3B8590FB83D36ADC!550&resid=3B8590FB83D36ADC!550&authkey=!ACKE9hDQI06CKgw&wdo=2&cid=3b8590fb83d36adc")
Error: `path` does not exist:

I had hoped this might work, but it simply downloads an HTML file without the data.
download.file(url = "https://onedrive.live.com/view?id=3B8590FB83D36ADC!550&resid=3B8590FB83D36ADC!550&authkey=!ACKE9hDQI06CKgw&wdo=2&cid=3b8590fb83d36adc",
              destfile = "~/downloads/test")

Is it possible to use a public link to an Office365 XLSX file to either download the file and save it to my machine or read the file directly into R?

Using curl gives The request is blocked. Btw, the URL says .../view?... maybe a hint that this is not the right way to get a working link to the data from onedrive?

That URL doesn't contain an XSLX file, you would have to find a url that actually points to an excel file, not to the web viewer of the file. Perhaps through an API, using something like the Microsoft365R package.

Elaborating on what @Axeman said, there's no .xlsx extension, which indicates an issue. However, you can also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857098/download-onedrive-file-from-curl-since-theyve-changed-their-urls-construction for how someone uses curl to download a file from the one drive API.
